# How to wire switch with 3 cables and outlet where only 1 is affected by switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

[image]

Here is a consolidated version of the situation. There's more outlets that repeat in series and I am not showing grounds. My Fiancee put a new fixture in the closet. It wouldn't turn on. We hired an electrician. They did not touch the new fixture, but did modify the wiring in at least light switch [A] and this is the current state.[image]
That week, the lamp connected to the bottom [D] outlet began to dim and then the outlet stopped working altogether. I would like help understanding if the wiring to [A] is correct to allow for [D] top to be always on, and [D] bottom to be switched on/off (the state it was in before he came). I can troubleshoot [D] better once I'm confident that [A] is wired appropriately. I've looked through many online resources but couldn't find one that showed a setup for a 3 wire, 3 cable box for a switch.

I do not know if [C] is supposed to affect [D] because we never used it. I am also not sure where [D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Jix.png) and [D][3] go. I'm hesitant to hire another electrician without knowing a bit more so I can ensure the work is done well. I've hired two in my area; the first ran conduit straight through rooms without junction boxes with the conduit screwed to the wall and the second wired the diagram in this post.

Comment: Some parts of this really don't make sense. Which of course could be why things don't work right. But actual pictures would clarify things quite a bit.

Comment: The switch A- switches the upper socket on the plug B, the switch C switches the lower socket on plug B but not the Porch light

Comment: It might be easier if you tell me what you want and I will advise. Like the Switch A to switch Closet light and Socket B... Switch C to switch Porch light and socket D

Comment: Honestly and politely your wiring makes no sense at all

Comment: Please provide actual pictures of the wiring. While your drawing isn't bad, there are probably details that you've left out or not gotten 100% accurate simply because you don't realize they're important, while the working electricians on this site will recognize these details immediately by being able to see the actual situation.

Comment: Think/research, don't experiment. Many combinations are out there which will work, and then kill you!  Also don't spam wires into the walls and hope for the best, make sure you are installing the wires you will need for your task.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just trying random things; this is the worst mindset for electricity.

Anyways, I think your main problem is that light switch A controls the power to everything after it, not just the closet light.

I'm pretty sure that I'll be downvoted for even attempting this but have a look at this picture. Hopefully it helps you to understand how a switch works.

[image]

I sincerely hope that those green triangles are wire nuts and that you're not randomly securing things to a metal box ground screw.

FYI, outlet D seems like a heinous safety hazard. Your breaker should be immediately tripping since you've connected the hot to the neutral.

Comment: *I sincerely hope that those green triangles are wire nut* That was my thought too. Since they twist (which is like a screw), someone totally unfamiliar with the terminology might call them screws. Of course, the color choice is not good - they seem to come (deliberately, I think) it just about every color *except* green.

Comment: The scary part is that a supposedly competent electrician did that work! Either that or our OP has incorrectly drawn the situation. That's why I asked for actual pics.

Comment: @FreeMan And I asked for pictures 13 hours before you did...but still no pictures.

Comment: Sometimes an extra prod works. Sometimes not...

Comment: For the record, I haven't tried anything. I am just trying to understand if A's current wiring made sense in the context of everything else. If it did, I'd feel comfortable replacing the outlet with the same wiring. If not, I would hire a different electrician. I only removed the outlets to diagram them. The green do represent wire nuts. I'll be reaching out to a 3rd electrician and hope they're better than the last two.